# Host two asp.net core applications on the same Ip and port (localhost:8080 for example)

Tags: asp.net-core, server, host, multiple-projects

I have two projects which are ASP.NET CORE servers (1 BackEnd and 1 Identity Server)
I would like the BackEnd to serve both apps on the same port and keep two separately runable projects.

[image: Project Structure]

How can I make this possible ? The purpose is to open only one port to the client.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are both apps hosted by IIS?

Answer (score 1):

> I have two projects which are ASP.NET CORE servers (1 BackEnd and 1 Identity Server) I would like the BackEnd to serve both apps on the same port and keep two separately runable projects.

If your App(s) are hosted on IIS, you can try to deploy your BackEnd service and Identity Server in two [separate applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/get-started/planning-your-iis-architecture/understanding-sites-applications-and-virtual-directories-on-iis#applications) under same web site as below.

[image]

Please note that the application's path would become part of the site's URL if we create an application in IIS. To make your Apps can work well, you may need to modify some code to include application's path in URL while you configure Identity Server to protect your BackEnd service.

Comment: Thanks, that could help

Comment: Hi @Rihen, if the solution did help achieve your requirement, you can accept it as answer.

Comment: @FeiHan I have a similar setup with a virtual directory with an index.html, and if I go BackEnd/mydir/ it opens the index.html, but if I go BackEnd/myAPI it returns 404. The API works fine if I create it's own website on a different port or from IIS Express launched from visual studio. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In IIS, you need to set a binding for each web application. Then each web application will respond to requests for the corresponding binding.